# How to inject customized validation on bootstrap form field

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap in my html form as below. It has a user name input field with a simple validation rule which is length must between 1 and 16 characters. I wonder how I can put more validation rules on this field. For example, I want to check the username must not start with a number and doesn't include special characters like `* # @` etc. I am fine if it requires some jquery code. But I don't know how to inject the validation logic and make it works wit the `with-errors` div.

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label for="user-username-input">User Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-username-input" placeholder="User Name" maxlength="16" data-minlength="1" data-error="Required" required>
              <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use html5 input pattern attribute.

```
       <form>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="user-username-input">User Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control"
                 id="user-username-input" placeholder="User Name" 
                 pattern="[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,16}"
                 title="Username should be alphanumeric of length upto 16 characters and first character can not be number." 
                 required>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
          <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </div>
       </form>
```